# How do I use Azure Devops TFS REST API to get older TestRuns of a TestPoint/TestCase/TestSuite?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

The API call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/points?api-version=7.0
```

Returns JSON data with objects "LastTestRun" and "LastTestResult" that contain their Ids. I am trying to find a proper way of getting older (not last) data of TestResults of the given TestPoint using API calls.

I tried the following API call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?planId=123
```

That returns me a list of all `TestRuns` in the given `TestPlan`. I can loop through the list and make API call for every single TestRun:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results
```

And, then retrieve the TestPointId. The problem is I'm working with large amounts of data, so I'm looping through 7000 API calls and it takes too much time (parallel of course).

I tried calling the last API call with `$select` so I can retrieve only the `TestPointId` but it is not supported.

A version of the AzureDevops I am working with: Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expectation, I have tested as well to get test results with only test point value and tested get the runs of a specific test case in a test suite. Neither succeeded.

Currently there seemed no official API support the test point filter. For this, you may access this URL: https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas to submit any comments and proposals for future releases and implementations.